# drupal admin.inc, loop list_modules as form settings

Tags: arrays, forms, drupal, loops

I need to loop the values of this

```
$blocks = array();

$blocks['list_modules']
```

with this:

```
$form['advanced']['custom_acc'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('module title'),
    '#options' => array(
      0 => t('No control'),
      1 => t('Controlled'),
      ),
  );
```

so it should become *something like* this

```
        while (list(, $value) = each($blocks)) {
        echo "

    $form['advanced']['custom_->blocks array value'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('->blocks array value'),
        '#options' => array(
          0 => t('No control'),
          1 => t('Controlled'),
          ),
      );
  ";
}
```

but of course this is not working, got any ideas? I guess I have to use an foreach, I hope you can see what Im trying to achieve,

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

fixed it myself :)

```
    $blocks = array();
$blocks = module_list();

foreach ($blocks as $key => $title) {

$form['advanced'][$title] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t($title),
    '#options' => array(
      0 => t('No control'),
      1 => t('Controlled'),
      ),
  );
}
```